# MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream() not able to find path in jars but works in .class file

Tags: java, jackson

`TileManager.class.getResourceAsStream("maps/Level_0.json")` works fine if I compile everything, but when I put it in a jar, it returned
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer`

My code for loading the JSON file is:

```
    String src = "/maps/Level_0.json";
        // default StandardCharsets.UTF_8

        InputStream is = TileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(src);

        assert is != null;
        content = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
                .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        System.out.println(content);
        data = Converter.fromJsonString(content);
```

The location of `Level_0.json` is `src/res/maps/Level_0.json` and `res` is a source folder.

[x] I have imported all the libraries into the jar file.

Comment: *"[x] I have imported all the libraries into the jar file."* - The evidence suggests that you haven't done it the right way. Putting a JAR inside another JAR won't work with the standard Java classloaders.

Comment: I use intelliJ IDEA. in the project settings, I included the libraries and selected them in artifacts

Comment: Also, the error is caused by ClassNotFoundException

Comment: That is further evidence that what you did in `[x]` is not sufficient.  I'm not familiar with Intellij, but you haven't said anything about how you are building the JAR.  A normal JAR does NOT contain the external libraries.